# Kestrel behind HAproxy or HAproxy and then Apache/Nginx

Tags: haproxy, kestrel-http-server, kestrel

I have a server that I need to set up for a web site which uses asp. The server runs Ubuntu 16.04 and serves multiple sites using HAproxy. I can get the site running, no problem, but I am not sure if I can have HAproxy work as the only redirection for Kestrel or I should have Apache or Nginx in between as well.

When it comes to Kestrel, it has some known flaws, as can be seen at [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction?tabs=aspnetcore2x) under "Securing our application". Can HAproxy secure the same flaws or should I still use a robust webserver in between?